# Using only part of CGAffineTransformIdentity

Tags: uiview, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform, affinetransform

Is there any way to only use certain aspects of the transform identity when I'm resetting something to its CGAffineTransformIdentity?

I have this method that resets my image view:

```
- (void)resetImage
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [firstImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

But I now want to make a new method that centers the image but leaves everything else about the transform i.e.(scale, rotation).

Is this something I can do simply so I can use an animation block like in my resetImage method? Or do I need to go a far more complicated route?

Thanks in advance!

*just as a warning, I have very little experience with CG so take it easy on me :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity transformation has no aspects. You're not saying “subtract all the things I did to it before” (such that you could exclude some of those things from the subtraction); you are resetting it to its initial, non-transformative value.

> But I now want to make a new method that centers the image but leaves everything else about the transform i.e.(scale, rotation).

I assume you mean “leaves everything else … out”.

Then you need to make a transformation that contains the translation(s), but not the scale or rotation.

Comment: I thought I understood the transform identity after reading this [http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html) But now I understand it has no values and is just a constant. I was hoping I could use an animation block but I'll just have to use a transform. Thanks!

Comment: @REDMX: That's not correct. You missed a key part of the sentence you're referring to. “it's… a 3x3 matrix, it's just that **certain values in** the matrix are constant, they can't change, so they're not represented by a variable.” (emphasis added) The rightmost column is constant, and so omitted from the structure. The other two columns, six cells, are in the structure—those are the values of a 2D affine transformation.